# Auto-web test : ExpectedResponseUrl error

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, automated-tests, asp.net-3.5

While running my auto-web test, I received this message :

> Response URL                Validation           The value of the ExpectedResponseUrl properity 'http://localhost:4800/FirstPage.aspx' isn't equal to the effective response URL  'http://localhost:4800/SecondPage.aspx'. The QueryString parameters have been ignored.

Note: for the redirection, I am using:

```
Response.Redirect(Url2, false);
```

event while changing the parameter with true, I receive the same message.

Comment: could you please translate the error message into English?

Comment: Could you post some more information about your test?  It looks like you are just asserting the wrong url?

Comment: Thanks alot dear Knvn and Buh Buh, I am soo sorry for the french message, i translated it.

Comment: I found the solution, and I didn't understand why! but it is Oky :

The solution is to use Server.Transfere() instead of Response.Redirect()

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and I didn't understand why! but it is Oky :

The solution is  to use Server.Transfere() instead of Response.Redirect()